# Trying to sort a string array but I seem to be stuck in the loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, selection

I can't seem to get out of this loop? I have 2 arrays, they are parallel arrays so that is why I have array2. the only thing the program gives me back is the same number everytime which is the number of elements the array has.

```
 void selectionSort(string array1[], string array2[], int size){

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (array1[j] < array1[minIndex])
                minIndex = j;
        swap(array1[minIndex], array1[i]);
        swap(array2[minIndex], array2[i]);

    }


}
```

Comment: Seems like you assume that `swap` statements are in the `if` body, or i am wrong?

Comment: "the only thing the program gives me back" what do you mean? There is neither a `return` nor a `cout`

Comment: xcode is giving me a number and the program just keeps running tobi. And Taha no the swap statements are suppose to be out of the if statement. The size is about 200000, so does it take this long for binary search to sort?

Comment: I dont know xcode and I still dont get it, the number of elements in the arrays does not change in the code, so what do you expect?

Comment: Maybe its because the size is 200,000 for the array?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If your array is really 200000 elements, you're looking at tens of *billions* of string comparisons; hope you packed a lunch. You said, "...so does it take this long for binary search to sort?" - there's no binary-search in this code whatsoever. This is brute-force silicon-spinning.

Answer (score -2):

why did you use the operator "<" for string. It can't work! GG for this and I think your idea about selection sort here is completely wrong. Your code just considers about array1[] and what about array2[]???.
That's my thought, sorry for my bad English!

Comment: I already do not understand the question, but this answer is even more confusing (or confused?). Of course `std::string` has a `operator<`